# Changing div clipping event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on a project that uses ByRei's DynDiv to use movable/scaleable divs. Everything seems to work fine except that when I want to minimize a div, using the included function, it seems to do so except for the fact that the clipping merely obscures the content, and it in fact remains the same height. After going through the source code, I think I've narrowed down why.

```
   if (evt) {
   var
    evt_src = (evt.target) ? evt.target : evt.srcElement,
    minmax_src = ByRei_dynDiv.get.parent(evt_src,ByRei_dynDiv.config.regExp.minmax,0),
    minmaxHeight = (ByRei_dynDiv.get.prefix.value(minmax_src.className.split(' '),"minmax_Height-",1)||20);
   evt_src = ByRei_dynDiv.get.parent(evt_src,ByRei_dynDiv.config.regExp.minmax,1);
   ByRei_dynDiv._style(evt_src,'clip', (new RegExp (minmaxHeight + "\\w+,?\\s?auto","i").test(ByRei_dynDiv._style(evt_src,'cl'))) ?  'rect(auto auto auto auto)' : 'rect(auto auto ' +  (minmaxHeight) +'px auto)');
}
```

https://code.google.com/p/mvp-log-api/source/browse/trunk/dyndiv.js?r=3

From what I can gather, it clips the element, making the visibility 0, but the div remains the same actual height. How would I go about changing this so that when the event occurs, the div actually changes in height instead of just visually "hiding" the content that is clipped? Rectify also seems involved.

Thank you very much for reading.